# Express $f(t) = \cos(4t)+\sin(6t)$ as trigonometric polynomial.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, fourier-analysis

I'm asked to express the function $f(t) = \cos(4t)+\sin(6t)$ as trigonometric polynomial of the form $\sum_{n=-N}^N c_ne^{inwt}$. My first approach was to use Euler's formula to arrive at $f(t)= \frac{1}{2}e^{i4t}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-i4t}+\frac{1}{2i}e^{i6t}-\frac{1}{2i}e^{-i6t}$, but I'm not sure if this is correct and how I would turn this into a series.

Comment: why wouldn't it be correct? most coefficients are zero but that's fine

Comment: @Conrad But my work is not done here, or is it?

Comment: why not? $N=6$ $c_n =0$ unless $n =\pm 4, n= \pm 6$ etc